# htaccess redirecting specific URL to new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm getting myself seriously confused with Rewrite Conditions and Rewrite Rules in my htaccess file.

Basically I have a new domain and want to redirect my articles to the new domain. For instance in someone visits old-domain.com/article/XYZ-article-title I want it to redirect to new-domain.com/article/XYZ-article-title.

Where I'm getting myself confused is that I only want it to redirect if /article is in the domain (the old domain is still in use for other stuff).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewritRule ^article(/.*)?$ http://new-domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```