# htaccess redirect to new domain maintaining all the url behind the host

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect to new domain while maintaining all the url behind the host.

I tried this and it doesn't work :
[htaccess redirecting specific URL to new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471648/htaccess-redirecting-specific-url-to-new-domain)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com\.my$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/.*)?$ https://www.domain.my%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Whenever I type https://www.domain.com.my/page1/page2  the browser will still load https://www.domain.my/page1/page2

I want it to show https://www.domain.my/page1/page2

I have tried most of the answers from this site.

The `%{REQUEST_URI}$` never work.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com\.my$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.my%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

The difference is the mathcing pattern in your rule. Why does that make a difference? Because your previous pattern never matched when used in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"). That actually is documented clearly. You really should start to read the documentation of the tools you use:

In distributed configuration files the pattern is matched against the *relative* request path, as opposed to situations where the pattern is used in the http server's real host configuration. That actually does make a lot of sense, once you thin about it.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).